# Outlook forward if specific person is not in recipient list

Tags: email, outlook, forward

At my company we have for our team a general mailbox. What I would like to do is to forward mails send to this mailbox to teammembers that were not in the recipient list. So for example, a mail is send to the general mailbox and that of my colleague, I'm not in TO or CC. The general mailbox should forward it to me and not my colleague. If my colleague wasn't also in recipient list, the mail should be forward to both of us.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Many thanx in advance!

Comment: Ask non-programming questions on the http://www.superuser.com web site instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest way is to set up a rule in Outlook or on the server-side.

Also you may consider developing a VBA macro which can be run in Outlook when the rule triggers. The macro sub should be in the following format:

```
 Public Sub Test(mail As MailItem)
    ' your code
 End Sub
```

See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: this answer does not seem to address the questions intent. i believe that the question wants to know what parameters in an Outlook rule would allow for the specified behavior.